# Master Thesis within Data Science with restricted knowledge and time

Tags: thesis, research-proposal, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

We are two double-degree students within the fields of business and data science. Our goal was to write a master thesis within the department of business & management and change it accordingly so it would be accepted at the department of data science. However, we have realized that it is not possible and that we probably will have to write an additional thesis specifically within the field of data science. As both I and my colleague have accepted job offerings after the summer we would like to complete this thesis during the summer which implies several limitations. Secondly, it should be noted, that we dont know what subject area we could write about. Thereby I would like to leverage the help from this community to provide us with some guidance regarding what I and my colleague could write a thesis about. Out limitations are as follows:

- **Time**: In total, we can work on the thesis for 3 months 40-50h/w
- **Skillset**: As grad students within the field of business & management we are well versed in reading and writing reports.
- **Knowledge**: Basic knowledge within the field of AI. We are well aware of the basic learning algorithms for NLP, image recognition, large-scale data, and recommendation systems. We have worked with neural networks, but have quite a basic understanding of deep neural networks and their associated architecture.
- **Supervisors**: As this will be performed during the summer, the availability of a supervisor will most likely be limited to some extent.
- **Content**: The requirement from the department is that the thesis has to be "within the field of data science", but not more specific than that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Get a thesis supervisor from the department of data science, and ask them for help. It is impossible for us to know what the department of data science at your university demands of a master thesis, and this varies widely between departments, so we cannot give you the advice you seek.